# add rows to datagrid view

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have datagridview contain data from database.

```
dgvSuratPemesanan.DataSource = detailSuratPemesananM.DisplayDetailSuratPemesanan(noSurPem2);
```

[image]

Now, I want to add new row. I've tried this:

```
dRow = dTable.NewRow();
                    dRow["ID"] = idProduk;
                    dRow["ID PRODUK"] = idProduk;
                    dRow["NAMA PRODUK"] = tbNamaProduk.Text.Trim();
                    dRow["QUANTITY"] = tbQuantity.Text.Trim();
                    dRow["SATUAN"] = unit;
                    dRow["HARGA"] = hargaHna;
                    dRow["SUBTOTAL"] = subTotal2;
                    dgvSuratPemesanan.Rows.Add(dRow);
```

but, the row from datasource is disappear, and replaced by the new row.

How to add new row without replacing the row from datasource?

I've been googling all day, but find no answer for it.
thx in advance!

Comment: How do you bring your data from `dTable` to your gridview? Do you overwrite the DataSource?

Comment: seems i overwrite the datasource because im adding this `dgvSuratPemesanan.DataSource = dTable;`

Answer (score 0):

If the `DataGridView` is data bound to some data source then you cannot add new rows/columns. You will have to create a new data set (DataTable or whatever) with the required columns and then re-bind the `DataGridView` to that.
in your case you have already set the `datasource` by

```
dgvSuratPemesanan.DataSource = detailSuratPemesananM.DisplayDetailSuratPemesanan(noSurPem2);
```

I hope this helps.

**updates:**

```
  DataTable dTemp = detailSuratPemesananM.DisplayDetailSuratPemesanan(noSurPem2); 
dtTemp.rows.add(1);
integer introw=dtTemp.rows.count-1;
    dtTemp.rows(intcount).item() = dTemp.NewRow(); 
    dtTemp.rows(intcount).item("ID") = noSurPem2; 
    dtTemp.rows(intcount).item("ID PRODUK") = idProduk; 
    dtTemp.rows(intcount).item("NAMA PRODUK") = tbNamaProduk.Text.Trim(); 
    dtTemp.rows(intcount).item("QUANTITY") = tbQuantity.Text.Trim(); 
    dtTemp.rows(intcount).item("SATUAN") = unit; 
    dtTemp.rows(intcount).item("HARGA") = hargaHna;
    dtTemp.rows(intcount).item("SUBTOTAL") = subTotal2;
    dgvSuratPemesanan.DataSource = dtTemp;
```

Comment: what should i do then, sir?

Comment: already given you a solution.You will have to create a new data set (DataTable or whatever) with the required columns and then re-bind the `DataGridView` to that.

Comment: in simple ways,take all the data from that datasource and fill it inot some datatable or something.then add required number of rows to that datatable.then finally set the new datatable as datagridview datasource

Comment: like this right? [IMG]http://i60.tinypic.com/2d82kht.png[/IMG] . but still got error sir

Comment: no? then how sir? noSurpem2 is Order Number sir, just an id.

Comment: dont set data source for `dgvSuratPemesanan`.Fill all the data from `detailSuratPemesananM.DisplayDetailSuratPemesanan(noSurPem2)` to a temp datatable .can you do it as post that code as text?

Comment: `DataTable dTemp = detailSuratPemesananM.DisplayDetailSuratPemesanan(noSurPem2);

                    dRow = dTemp.NewRow();
                    dRow["ID"] = noSurPem2;
                    dRow["ID PRODUK"] = idProduk;
                    dRow["NAMA PRODUK"] = tbNamaProduk.Text.Trim();
                    dRow["QUANTITY"] = tbQuantity.Text.Trim();
                    dRow["SATUAN"] = unit;
                    dRow["HARGA"] = hargaHna;
                    dRow["SUBTOTAL"] = subTotal2;

                    dTemp.Rows.Add(dRow);

    `

Comment: look updated code.may be its not fully correct but a light to your problem.now modify it and find out more by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**

First You need to get table back from assigned datasource .

```
var noSurPem2 = (DataTable)dgvSuratPemesanan.DataSource;
```

Then you Add New Row in Datatable

```
var dRow = noSurPem2.NewRow();
                    dRow["ID"] = idProduk;
                    dRow["ID PRODUK"] = idProduk;
                    dRow["NAMA PRODUK"] = tbNamaProduk.Text.Trim();
                    dRow["QUANTITY"] = tbQuantity.Text.Trim();
                    dRow["SATUAN"] = unit;
                    dRow["HARGA"] = hargaHna;
                    dRow["SUBTOTAL"] = subTotal2;
                    noSurPem2.Rows.Add(dRow);
```

After Creating new Row Assign datasource back to gridview

```
dgvSuratPemesanan.DataSource = noSurPem2;
```

**Method 2**

Using the cloning technique

```
DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)dgvSuratPemesanan.Rows[0].Clone();
                    row.Cells["ID"] = idProduk;
                    row.Cells["ID PRODUK"] = idProduk;
                    row.Cells["NAMA PRODUK"] = tbNamaProduk.Text.Trim();
                    row.Cells["QUANTITY"] = tbQuantity.Text.Trim();
                    row.Cells["SATUAN"] = unit;
                    row.Cells["HARGA"] = hargaHna;
                    row.Cells["SUBTOTAL"] = subTotal2;
                    dgvSuratPemesanan.Rows.Add(row);
```

Comment: the method doesn't work mr. the program just break from the first line of the method :'(

Comment: what about second method ?

Comment: i just got this errors from the second one [IMG]http://i59.tinypic.com/1zxlajd.png[/IMG]